# Table Row Count Validation plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to validate two tables row count, but it throws an error like missing keyword.

```
Declare

source_count number := 0;
target_count number := 0;
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO source_count FROM TABLE1';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO target_count FROM TABLE2';

IF source_count = target_count THEN 

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Copied Count matched with Table1 and TABLE2');

ELSE

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Count mismatch');
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error '||sqlerrm);
END;
/
```

Comment: If this is part of your [migration exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65438518/230471), remember that in PL/SQL, you can capture `sql%rowcount` immediately after any DML operation such as an `insert`, so you don't need to count the table to find out how many rows you have inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INTO` outside the string in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or even dont use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO source_count FROM TABLE1;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO target_count FROM TABLE2;
```

If you need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` then use following:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1' INTO source_count;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2' INTO target_count;
```

Comment: If your tables are known at compile time, then skip the "execute immediate" part. Just run SELECT COUNT(*) INTO source_count FROM TABLE1;